# Change NavigationBar background on UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have to pass a local PDF file (documents directory) from UIWebView to other apps (iBooks, Facebook Messenger, WhatsApp, ...).

So i use UIDocumentInteractionController:

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString];

    self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    self.docController.delegate = self;
    [self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
}
```

If i select FB Messenger or WhatsApp it shows a ViewController.

How can i change the NavigationBar appearance of this VC (background image/color, button tint)? Default white translucent would be nice.

I set a NavigationBar background image in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
- (void)openEC:(NSURL*)url {  
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];  
docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];  
[docController setDelegate:self];  
[docController  presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {  
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

}

Comment: Yeah this works. I can't remove the background image that i set in AppDelegate, so i removed this and set the image in my ViewController.

Comment: @KevinHösel: if this works then please accept the answer

Comment: In some Apps the bar tint or button tint doesn't change. I think there is nothing i can do?

Answer (score 2):

if you use this line then Just remove this line and everything works well.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

As for the Status Bar Style, the simplest way would be to pass self.navigationController as the presenter, instead of self:

```
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
   return self.navigationController;
}
```

It may be helpful to you