# Is there any way to change the title colour of UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

I am trying to change the default title colour of the view presented by UIDocumentInteractionController? The default color is balck and the only property available is title.

Comment: I was able to change the background colour and tint color, but not the title color.

Comment: `tintColor` will change the title color also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703314/change-navigationbar-background-on-uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Answer (score 0):

**in swift**

```
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController 
{
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]  
        return self.navigationController ?? self
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.